# Recompiling OpenWRT - what 'make' commands are needed to include any changes while saving time on unaffected files

Tags: makefile, compilation, openwrt

I'm exploring the effect on my router of various source changes to OpenWRT.

I've cloned the relevant release's tag to a new local branch with git. I plan to hack around with the code and see if I like any changes - if I do, I'll make formal patches for them later. The build compiles happily. But as I'm compile-test-modifying, I'm unclear how to minimise the work that `make` has to do, to rewcompile it with any changes.

I know that `make` is designed to minimise recompilation by detecting files that need downloading vs files already downloaded/existing, and files changed vs files unchanged. But I can't figure what `make` commands to issue (make clean/make distclean/other), to clean up after compiling, for the next compile, without including outdated artifacts from the previous run.

Example:

- I run `make menuconfig`, set up basic choices (no point doing more at this point), then `make download`, then `make -j6 -V=sc -d --trace` (overkill and probably duplicative, I know, but it's OK)
- If the build works, I get a .squashfs file in the output dir. Yay!
- I now want to modify a patch in the git dir. Or perhaps change a few lines in some of the downloaded tools/python files in `build_dir` that were downloaded/created by the previous run.
  For example, `make` downloads and creates files in `~/openwrt/build_dir/target-arm_cortex-a9_musl_eabi/hostapd-wpad-mini`, I edit them rather than adding patches because it's simpler for ad-hoc testing.
  *(I agree that I could add patches for the latter and allow them to redownload, but when recompiling on an ad-hoc basis for testing, it's simpler + quicker for me, if* `make` *keeps the previously downloaded versions, and builds from the modded versions without forcing them to be downloaded again or having to create patches for them.)*
- I now want to recompile. But I want to be sure `make` will notice my changes to scripts, downloaded tools, and downloaded data files, if any, and build me a new build that includes these, without having to redownload unchanged files, deleting modified files (so I have to change them via patches each time), and definitely overwriting the existing output files.

I'm not entirely clear what `make` typically removes and checks, or how it's been configured specifically for OpenWRT, so I hope the question is valid as asked.

What commands should I issue to ensure my new build includes changes but "takes for granted" any files it already finds were downloaded, but rebuilds anything based on them, if they've been edited?

Comment: Those aren't intrinsic make "commands", they're targets and are entirely the responsibility of the maintainer. There's no one solution that will work for every single project that relies on make. Ideally it should be documented in the build instructions, although there are some conventions: [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Standard-Targets), [automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Clean.html).

Answer (score 0):

For a simple example of editing source files, I just run `make` again.  The build process doesn't need to download files again, but it does recompile the updated source.  To verify the updates were built, make sure the package is updated: For example, hostapd-wpad-mini's package should be in `~/openwrt/bin/packages/[arch]/base`.
To save time, you can re-install just that package to the device instead of reflashing the entire image.  You'll probably need to force-reinstall (`opkg --force-reinstall install [package-path]`) because the package version won't have changed.

Be **warned**: wpad, hostapd, wpa_supplicant are all different build configurations of the same code base, but that code is extracted into a separate directory within `~/openwrt/build_dir` for each configuration.  Modifying the source for one configuration  will not update the other. (A change you make in hostapd won't actually be built into the wpa_supplicant configuration.)  To be sure you're testing thoroughly, update the code with a patch in `~/openwrt/package/network/services/hostapd/patches` so it's applied to all variants.  If you create updates to the patches, you can force a clean and rebuild of just the package(s) you're interested in: `make package/[package-name]/{clean,compile} V=s`.  This will not cause the squash image to be rebuilt, but as noted above, you can just install the updated package.

When making changes to a package configuration, I always clean the package, update it (`./scripts/feeds update [repo-name]`) and rebuild it.  If dependencies of the package changed, a full make make be required.